# Windows Phone 8 Facebook LoginWithApp no longer works for me

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Since this morning the Facebook SDK no longer seems to be able to login with the Facebook app. When I call the FacebookSessionClient.LoginWithApp() method found in the C# SDK it will open up Facebook and then proceed to open up a webframe with the Facebook website login. When credentials are filled in on the webframe the app wont issue callback to the original app and thus you can no longer login to Facebook.

I have tested this on two devices and both dont seem to work.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue or is this a known issue with a solution?

This is my RelayCommand calling the method

```
public RelayCommand LoginButton
    {
        get
        {
            return _loginButton = _loginButton ??
                new RelayCommand(() =>
                    {
                        var fbSessionClient = new FacebookSessionClient("app_id");
                        fbSessionClient.LoginWithApp("email,basic_info,user_friends", "secret_string");
                    });
        }
    }
```

My UriMapperBase Handler

```
    class FacebookAppAuthenticationHelper : UriMapperBase
{
    public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
        return new LoginViewModel().MapUri(uri);
    }
}
```

My Facebook URI callback handler

```
public Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
        // if URI is a facebook login response, handle the deep link (once per invocation)
        if (AppAuthenticationHelper.IsFacebookLoginResponse(uri))
        {
            FacebookSession session = new FacebookSession();

            try
            {
                session.ParseQueryString(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ToString()));

                // Handle success case
                FacebookAuthorized = true;

                // do something with the custom state parameter
                if (session.State != "secret_string")
                {
                    //nop
                }
                else
                {
                    // save the token and continue (token is retrieved and used when the app is lauched)
                    FacebookSettings.AccessToken = session.AccessToken;
                    FacebookSettings.FacebookId = session.FacebookId;
                    FacebookSettings.TokenExpires = session.Expires;
                }
            }
            catch (Facebook.FacebookOAuthException)
            {
                if (!this.facebookLoginHandled)
                {
                    // Handle error case
                    this.facebookLoginHandled = true;
                    // return to a different uri
                    FacebookSettings.FacebookId = null;
                    FacebookSettings.AccessToken = null;
                    FacebookSettings.TokenExpires = DateTime.MinValue;
                }
            }
            FacebookSettings.Save();
            return new Uri("/View/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        }

        // by default, navigate to the requested uri
        return uri;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I've added my code, like I said though, it only stopped working this morning. I have not changed any of this code since last week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this problem was on Facebook's side, and is fixed with todays update.